# How do I change the menu language of Excel Online?

Tags: office365, office-js

We are trying to do screenshots of Excel Online (for the the Office Store listing of an Add-In in a different language).

How do I change the language of the Excel menu (temporarily)?

I tried to change the language in the workbook creation dialog. It worked, but it only affected that dialog (but not the open workbook).

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can change your language setting.

1. from any workbook, click on App launcher (the waffle shaped button on the top left corner.)
2. Click on Excel Online.
3. You will see a landing page with Recent Tab on the left. See [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jom9.jpg).
4. The change language setting button is on the bottom left corner.

Hope it helps.

Thanks,
Sky

Comment: That button changes the language of the open dialog. But not the language of menu that appears as soon as I have opened/created the workbook

Comment: Same as Ruediger Jungbeck, but then I clean up the cookies and now it works

Comment: doesn't work in 2019, if you're using sharepoint you have to go to your profile, click three dots and select "edit language and region" from dropdown, it took me 15min to find it :/

Comment: I haven't seen change language setting on bottom left corner.